weird previous-command behavior in byobu with elapsed time in prompt
I'm using byobu on 24.10, and there is some very strange behavior when using ctrl-P to show the previous command when (1) the previous command wraps to the next line, and (2) the elapsed time is part of the prompt.
When I do this, the place where I see the cursor, and the place that text is inserted into the edited command, are different.
For example: I have
[0.009s] me@machine:/tmp/a_directory_with_oh_such_a_very_long_name_five_boxing_wizards_jumped_quickly_4747474747363221987426874623948762387645239807423087$ ls file-1-with-a-long-name-
rurioewrewuioewrioweuoiwuepweoiurpoiuewr 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 0 Dec  7 06:59 file-1-with-a-long-name-rurioewrewuioewrioweuoiwuepweoiurpoiuewr
me@machine:/tmp/a_directory_with_oh_such_a_very_long_name_five_boxing_wizards_jumped_quickly_4747474747363221987426874623948762387645239807423087$ 

Note that the command wraps after name- in the line where I run ls.
Now I want to edit that command and change something not at the very end -- say I need to add in a flag after the command. I use ctrl-P, then ctrl-A and I now I see:
[0.009s] me@machine:/tmp/a_directory_with_oh_such_a_very_long_name_five_boxing_wizards_jumped_quickly_4747474747363221987426874623948762387645239807423087$ ls file-1-with-a-long-name-rurioewrewuioewrioweuoiwuepweoiurpoiuewr 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 0 Dec  7 06:59 file-1-with-a-long-name-
rurioewrewuioewrioweuoiwuepweoiurpoiuewr
me@machine:/tmp/a_directory_with_oh_such_a_very_long_name_five_boxing_wizards_jumped_quickly_4747474747363221987426874623948762387645239807423087$ 423087$ ls file-1-with-a-long-name-
rurioewrewuioewrioweuoiwuepweoiurpoiuewr 

Look at the last line there: it shows the $ part of the prompt twice:
...9807423087$ 423087$ ls file-1-with-a-long...`

It's repeating the "423087" bit. Moreover, the cursor shows up at the first $. If I move forward so that I see the cursor after the ls  and edit, then hit enter, I see:
me@machine:/tmp/a_directory_with_oh_such_a_very_long_name_five_boxing_wizards_jumped_quickly_4747474747363221987426874623948762387645239807423087$ 423087$ ls -h ith-a-long-name-rurio
ewreurioewrewuioewrioweuoiwuepweoiurpoiuewr 
ls: cannot access 'file-1-w-h': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'ith-a-long-name-rurioewrewuioewrioweuoiwuepweoiurpoiuewr': No such file or directory

I tried to add -h, but the shell got that as part of the filename. What is being shown and what gets sent to the shell are different.
What is causing this, and how can I fix it? It is some kind of tmux bug? Is it related tot the weird thing with elapsed time on the far left?

This is somehow related to byobu's special PS0 and PS1 prompts. If I run byobu-disable-prompt, I get my regular bash prompt back, and things work as expected.
So this seems to be a bug with that prompt's $PS1, which for me is:
[0.011s] me@machine:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e[38;5;202m\]$(byobu_prompt_status)\[\e[00m\]$(byobu_prompt_runtime) \[\e[38;5;245m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[38;5;172m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[38;5;5m\]\w\[\e[00m\]$(byobu_prompt_symbol)

Something with the escape sequences is broken. I don't know what; if I go any further down a rabbit hole here, though, I'll end up in the earth's molten core of iron...
Just disabling the prompt with byobu-disable-prompt is good enough for me.

same problem. A possible workaround to get a clean command line is to edit the line at its end (sometimes it clears the eccess parts) or try to go up one line more and then back down again one line. Hope the author(s) will fix this soon !
